# pg_dump and pg_restore: "Error Segmentation fault (core dumped)" when altering table of contents

Tags: postgresql, database-backups, pg-dump, pg-restore

I am currently trying to establish a database backup workflow when I change my database schema.

For backuping the data (Only the data) I run this command:

```
pg_dump --data-only --compress=0 --encoding=utf8 -U my_user -F d -f backup_directory_name my_db_name
```

This creates a new folder with one file for each table and a table of contents file `toc.dat`.

Now I am changing my database schema, lets say I add a new boolean-column `isencrypted` to the table `properties`. My backup is out of date now and doesn't fit the schema.

How do I proceed?

`toc.dat` entry for table `properties` before altering data:

```
    ...@^@^@?^@^@^@COPY properties (key, createdat, updatedat, value) FROM stdin;
```

related table backup file holding all entries for table `properties` before altering data:

```
mail.subject.verification       \N      \N      Mailadresse bestätigen
```

**Now I alter both files to match the new schema:**

`toc.data` entry for table `properties` after altering data:

```
    ...@^@^@?^@^@^@COPY properties (key, createdat, updatedat, value, isencrypted) FROM stdin;
```

related table backup file after altering data:

```
mail.subject.verification       \N      \N      Mailadresse bestätigen  f
```

If I try to restore that table now, I get an error.
Restore-Command:

```
$ pg_restore -U my_user --data-only --table=properties --format=d -d my_db_name backup_directory_name
```

Error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

If I change the `toc.dat` and backup files back to how they were the error is gone (well, the inserts will fail obviously because the schema is different).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so I am getting a downvote for 2 spelling errors?

Comment: Why don't you create the backup after you add the column? Alternatively, use the plain sql for dump, which you can then edit.

Comment: I am using JPA / hibernate (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html), and I have to set the 'hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto' value from 'validate' to 'create' , resulting a complete loss of all data as the schema is recreated. I wanted to have separate files so I dont mess up other stuff. also, the file might get huge

Comment: I did **not** downvote (and I don't think the question deserves one)

Comment: haha sorry then, looked like it :) thanks for editing, I was in a hurry and this problem made me mad

Comment: Try to get a stack trace of the dump. Unless there is data corruption, `pg_restore` should not crash. It might be a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it contains some readable strings like `COPY properties (key, createdat, updatedat, value, isencrypted) FROM stdin;` the `toc.dat` is a binary file. In bytes between these strings are probably binary encoded their lengths, which stopped being correct after you added `, isencrypted` to the file, causing a segmentation fault error on bad data.

Instead of hacking the `toc.dat` file you can just skip the table during restore and then import it manually using `psql`:

```
psql my_dbname -c '\copy properties (key, createdat, updatedat, value, isencrypted) from 12345678.dat'
```